# spring java mail smtp connection issue with outlook server

Tags: spring, office365, jakarta-mail

i am trying to send mail through spring java mail API and my mail server is outlook.

so i am facing below issues.

sometimes it make connection to smpt host and sometimes it return connection timeout.

below i am pasting stacktrace .

```
SMTP host:example.com.mail.protection.outlook.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailS                                                                                        enderImpl.java:404)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSen                                                                                        derImpl.java:332)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSen                                                                                        derImpl.java:347)
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSen                                                                                        derImpl.java:336)
        at com.condivision.rentongo.service.MailService.sendMail(MailService.jav                                                                                        a:75)
        at com.condivision.rentongo.service.MailService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$                                                                                        $1ed18523.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:2                                                                                        04)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterce                                                                                        ptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:649)
        at com.condivision.rentongo.service.MailService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$                                                                                        5228ed74.sendMail(<generated>)
        at com.condivision.rentongo.service.OrderService.updateOrderAndInventory                                                                                        Status(OrderService.java:726)
        at com.condivision.rentongo.service.OrderService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB                                                                                        $$a056f002.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:2                                                                                        04)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation                                                                                        .invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(                                                                                        ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.
```

Comment: Looks like a network problem.  Do you have a firewall that might be causing problems?  Do you otherwise have poor internet connectivity?

Comment: @BillShannon actually first time  it sends mail but when it connects second time then i am getting this exception.

Comment: Ok, that's an important detail you failed to mention originally!  :-)  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show when it succeeds and when it fails?  Are you sure you're closing any connections after the first time?

Comment: actually i tried all the things and connection was getting close properly but later on i got to know that outlook mail server has buffer of 3 minutes to send another mail after one mail through java mail API .

Is outlook mail server really has buffer of 3 minutes ? is that true ,have you ever face such kind of issue ?

Comment: Yes, mail servers can set a rate limit to prevent you from using them to send spam.

Comment: alright ... thanks for the help  @BillShannon